# Connect WordPress Customizer CSS to style.css

Tags: css, wordpress

Any CSS the customizer generates will be written directly into the head section.
The customizer API uses the wp_head hook for that.

I would like to take hold of this CSS somehow and connect it to style.css.

What I want to do is the following:

1. The Customizer spits out a class .red {color:red;}
2. I'd like to grab this information and transfer it into my style.css somehow.

Ideally the Customizer CSS would be inserted at the beginning of my style.css

EDIT Just to clarify: By "Customizer CSS" I am referring to CSS information generated by a color picker control for example. Not the CSS from that "Custom CSS" input field – this one I can just copy and paste into my style.css

One idea is to save the customizer CSS output not in the head section via wp_head but somewhere else, into a file for example.

How can I do that? 
Is there a hook for that, is it even possible and does it make sense?

This is just one idea of mine – I am open to completely different approaches as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think writing into a file directly is not a good idea at all. Because next time the value is changed, the previous written CSS would be unnecessary. Dynamic values should be changeable. As you write the output value into the file as suggested, the previous generated value will always be there which is redundant.

The best approach would be using `wp_add_inline_style` Refer [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style).

Use the following method to add the CSS to the refereed file:

```
function my_styles_method() {
  $color = get_theme_mod( 'color-picker-control' ); //E.g. #FF0000
  $custom_css = "
        .mycolor{
            background: sachet;
        }";
  wp_add_inline_style( 'main-style', $custom_css ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into that. 
You are perfectly right in pointing out that writing into a file would be a quite stupid thing. My fault ;o)